# Modifying word template and printing it using C#

Tags: c#, templates, printing, ms-word, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a windows form application that can be used to administrate data from a car service, data like clients, cars, repairs done, etc.
The repairs that have been made to each car will be printed, on a word template which i have created, the problem is I dont know how should i add text to my template. I am using a reader to iterate through every repair done to a specific car, data is saved in SQLite database.
I was thinking about saving those repairs somewhere, and then use foreach to add them to my word template one after another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) library to work with *.doc / *.docx files. Or another variant is [OpenXml SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), it is from Microsoft, it is very powerfull, but as i know it supports only docx files (xlsx, pptx also).

Answer (score 0):

It's strange you **don't know** how to populate "word template" with data, but already created template - why??
There is standard solution - Reports. It can be printed or exported to PDF, DOC, whatever. One of 'em is FastReport - small and quite easy to use.